# circle bounded filtering

Tags: filters

Apologies if this has not been worded correctly.

I have a blue object that quickly changes velocity.

I would like to create a filter. I imagine it to be a circle around the blue circle that when intersected moves with it. Similar to the below illustration (green circle)

Is there a mathematical formula that exists for this method? If not what is it?

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you call a filter ? Think that we are not living in your world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given time let $(x,y)$ be the center of the little circle, and let's say it has radius $r$. Let $(X,Y)$ be the center of the big bigger circle and let it have radius $R$

First, you need a condition to check whether the smaller circle is entirely contained within the larger circle. If it is you don't need to do anything.

The smaller is contained within the larger as long as the distances between the centers is smaller than $R - r$. Draw a picture with the smaller at the edge of the larger to convince yourself of this.

Mathematically this corresponds to

$$(x - X)^2 + (y - Y)^2 < (R - r)^2$$

using the Pythagorean theorem for distance. As long as this holds instruct your code to do nothing.

If however, the smaller circle has moved outside the larger one you need some way of moving the larger one. How to best do this depends a little on whether you want 'snapping' or would like the large sphere to lag a little, which simulates acceleration.

**Option 1.** Let me sketch the crudest possible **crudest snapping solution** as a starter. This one is unstable and will glitch in some use-cases but doesn't require vector -algebra.

Let's say in the next frame the smaller circle has moved to coordinates $(x', y')$ placing it partially outside the big circle. Then we want to move the big circle just enough so it tangents the small circle again. The easiest way to do this is to move the big circle exactly as much as the small circle moved in-between frames which was $x' - x$ in the x-direction and $y' - y$ in the y-direction. So the new updated coordinates for the large circle should be

$$X' = X + (x' - x)$$
$$Y' = Y + (y' - y)$$

The above solution is literally 6(ish) lines of code so it's easy to implement. It will, however, behave weirdly in some cases and assumes the small circle started within the large one as they otherwise move out of sync.

Use it as a starter and see if it sufficient or if you need something more robust.

[image: movement]

Comment: I just want to say thanks for looking at my question in such depth and giving me such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two circles overlap when the distance between the centers is smaller than the sum of the radii.

A circle tangents another internally when the distance between the centers is the difference of the radii.

If you move a circle that tangents another internally in an outer direction, the two centers follow the same trajectory.

The common tangent is orthogonal to the line of the centers.